# How do the capacitor & resistor actually introduce a delay in the following oscillating circuit in terms of direct current?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdPcSX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How, in terms of direct current, do the capacitor and resistor actually create the delay and still permit the oscillation given that DC cannot pass through the capacitor.
If DC cannot pass through the capacitor, how is the base of transistor Q2 triggered?
Also why don't both LEDs stay lit?
Please bear in mind that I am self-taught and still relatively new to electronics.

Comment: One of the first things a self-taught electronics hobbyist needs to learn is to stop focusing on electrons. Think about currents and voltages. Thinking about things on an electron level only makes things needlessly confusing, and is only necessary in situations unlikely to come up in hobby work.

Comment: Is this circuit "working" ?

Comment: Where did you get your circuit from? Is it your own invention or is there a source you can quote? If it had a second capacitor it would look like an oddly drawn astable multivibrator but as drawn I'm not convinced it will oscillate at all. I'm glad to see you've moved on from trying to analyze it in terms of electron flow but you can't analyse this just in terms of direct current. It shows transient behaviour and a rigorous analysis requires understanding differential equations. There are however non-mathematical descriptions of astable multivibrator operation available via a search engine.

Comment: please try to observe the convention of drawing your circuits with the (positive) DC supply at the top, ground at the bottom, and arrange components logically in between them. Given that there is a sort of analogy between height and voltage (both potential energy) it makes your diagram a lot more intuitive to read.

Comment: @Graham Nye: I got the circuit from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vRAACeebjI and I've built it and it does indeed oscillate. The oscillating bit of the video occurs around 9:50. - J R

Comment: @GrahamNye: I got the circuit from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vRAACeebjI and I've built it and it does oscillate. The bit of the video on oscillating circuits starts at around 9:50.

Comment: The circuit in the video (e.g. at 13:30) is different from the one in your picture. The right-hand side of C1 connects to the collector of Q1 not to R1.

Comment: @GrahamNye: My sincere apologies. Thank you for spotting it for me. Does it now make the oscillating circuit easier to explain because for me, my original questions still apply, i.e. I'm just looking for the order of events, including the role of the cap

Comment: @GrahamNye: My sincere apologies. Thank you for spotting it for me. Are you now able to explain the order of events that lead to the the slowed down oscillation rather than simply stating that the RC circuit slows down the oscillation?

Comment: I don't currently have time to write a full answer. Now you have corrected your circuit someone else may be along to provide one. In the meantime look at the link in user368031's answer which describes the operation of a standard astable multivibrator, with a pair of RC timing networks. Your circuit diagram links to a simulator so you can use that to investigate voltages and currents around the capacitor(C). Your single C circuit works because it takes time to both charge and discharge the C. https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html discusses charging (& discharging on the next page).

Comment: Take a look here https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/astable-multivibrator-how-does-it-work.32164/#post-200183 or here https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/astable-multivibrator/  Any additional questions?

Answer (score 2):

This circuit doesn't have what's needed to oscillation. It's not a multivibrator nor other pulse oscillator  nor a sinewave oscillator. There's no feedback which causes enough phase lag for sinewaves or delay for pulses. Scrap this and restart by examining known pulse or sinewave oscillators. The two-transistor astable multivibrator is a good one.

See this https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html

[image]

By the way the answer to the title question: No way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but is a redraw of your schematic in a more conventional layout.

In general we draw with the higher potentials at the top and lower at the bottom. That way current flows from top to bottom. Normally *signal* flow will be from left to right (for things like amplifiers, etc.) but since this is a somewhat symmetrical circuit the layout has been done to emphasise that and to minimise (or eliminate) crossing wires.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWrHLi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Consider a simple series circuit:  Battery, switch, resistor, capacitor, return connection to the other end of the battery.

When a DC source is connected to a capacitor through a resistor, the capacitor begins to charge up through the resistor.  That is, charge flows from the source, through the resistor, into the capacitor.  As charge accumulates in the capacitor, the voltage across it increases.  Thus, even though the power source for the circuit is constant, the current through the circuit is changing.  The capacitor "sees" a changing voltage.

Eventually the voltage across the cap equals the voltage of the source, and electron flow stops.  There is an exponential equation that relates the resistor and capacitor values to the amount of time it takes the cap voltage to reach a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

If you feed a square wave into a simple low pass RC network, the output is related to the input like this:

[image]

Rather than sharp rise and fall times, there are gradual rise and fall times.

If the receiver of the *modified* wave has a threshold voltage, below which it treats the input as *off*, and above which it treats the input as *on*, the result will look something like this:

[image]

Notice that the result is *delayed* from the original square wave, because it takes time for the modified wave to reach the threshold compared to when the original square wave reaches its maximum or minimum.

This is how an RC network can provide a delay.